# Use values in different rows of a column as values in different columns but only one row

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, odoo-10

Is possible to group rows and use one value of each row for different custom columns?

Original table:

```
ID      Tax        Amount
--------------------------
 1      21%         33,40
 1      10%         15,30
 1       4%          1,32
 2      21%         12,43
 2      10%          4,20
```

Desired table:

```
ID     Tax 21%     Tax 10%     Tax 4%
--------------------------------------
 1      33,40       15,30       1,32
 2      12,43        4,20       0,00
```

How would you do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a postgresql or Odoo solution?

Comment: The two could be useful for acquiring an extra knowledge :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregate function sum()

```
SELECT ID,
       sum(CASE WHEN Tax = '21%' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) "Tax 21%",
       sum(CASE WHEN Tax = '10%' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) "Tax 10%",
      sum(CASE WHEN Tax = '4%' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) "Tax 4%"
FROM T
GROUP BY ID

id  Tax 21% Tax 10% Tax 4%
1   33.4    15.3    1.32
2   12.43   4.2     0
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7ae345710b6f3867fbaaa70ef93202d5)

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use condition aggregate function, `MAX` with `CASE WHEN`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT,
  Tax VARCHAR(50),
  Amount FLOAT
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'21%',33.40);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'10%',15.30);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'4%',1.32);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'21%',12.43);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'10%',4.20);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Tax = '21%' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) "Tax 21%",
       MAX(CASE WHEN Tax = '10%' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) "Tax 10%",
      MAX(CASE WHEN Tax = '4%' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) "Tax 4%"
FROM T
GROUP BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ec6d8/2/0)**:

```
| id | Tax 21% | Tax 10% | Tax 4% |
|----|---------|---------|--------|
|  1 |    33.4 |    15.3 |   1.32 |
|  2 |   12.43 |     4.2 |      0 |
```